# WCF service: How to access request data in global.asax

Tags: wcf, request, global-asax

How do I access data of the request body (specific `Data Member`) in the `global.asax` using a WCF service?

For example:

I created a WCF service project with a global.asax file for dependency injection:

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        //How to access request data here?
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

I have a `string GetData(Request request)` Operation Contract and I want to access a Data Member from the `Request` Data Contract within the `CreateKernel` method when a request was fired to my service.

Comment: It's not very clear.  What you mean by accessing request body?

Comment: You should post some sample code.  At a high level, you'd need to make the call to the WCF service in the global.asax file and then access the member there.